# What does やりすぎなほど mean on this page of Yotsubato!

Tags: words, usage, colloquial-language, manga

I am on ch.82, pg.19 of Yotsubato! manga. 
[image]
Source: http://raw.senmanga.com/Yotsubato!/82/19

What does 「やりすぎなほど」mean here ?

From what I know, 「ほど」 is used to express the extent of something and 「やりすぎ」 means overdoing/excessive etc., Does this translate to something like "Awesome!" ? Or does the literal translation mean something else?

Also, is the usage of「な」 here unconventional ? I have never really seen 「な」 used after noun so far (I am a beginner).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **よつば**: あのなー　キツツキみたよ！You know what? I saw a woodpecker!
>
> **葉介**: へー　どんなだった？Really? What was it like?
>
> **よつば**: きーつついてた！やりすぎなほど！It was pecking wood! Way too much (lit. to an extent that could be called overkill)!

The 「きーつついてた」 part, meaning the same as 「木をつついてた」, is a pun on 「キツツキ」.

「やりすぎなほど！」 is an additional comment to the previous pun. やりすぎ (overkill) is used as an adjective while it normally is just a verb-derived noun (do + too much). There is a similar question about the use of な after nouns [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/using-%e3%81%aa-particle-after-common-nouns-non-na-adjectives).

Note that it's perfectly grammatical to use な with na-adjectives like in ジョジョの**奇妙{きみょう}な**冒険{ぼうけん} (JoJo's **Bizarre** Adventure).

Comment: I thought it was the other bug guy who said that circled sentence. Makes a lot more sense now ! Thanks ! I checked out that link before asking this question. Just wanted to confirm that it was in fact unconventional use and it is, like you said. I will accept this answer.

Comment: 「きーつついてた」 is a colloquial/childlike way of pronouncing 「木、つついてた」, meaning 「木をつついていた」. cf. 「はーぬけた！」(歯が抜けた), 「ちーでてるよ～」(血が出てるよ)

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks. Missed that one. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @retrazil Fixed some misinformation about my answer. See Chocolate's comment